# Kotlin ktor library don't wait for all coroutines to finish in websockets handler

Tags: kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

Recently I was trying to implement simple web-socket application with Kotlin and [ktor](https://ktor.io/) library. My server just has single web-socket handler which I implement like the following:

```kotlin
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
    install(WebSockets)
    routing {
        webSocket("/handle") {
            // ... more domain specific logic which uses coroutines ...
            launch {
                for (message in incoming) {
                    // process message
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original code contains more logic which include starting a bunch of another coroutines - so `launch`-ing the `incoming` queue processing in separate coroutine doesn't look weird for me.

Unfortunally, the `ktor` closes the underlying web-socket connection as soon, as inner block function finished. This was unexpected behaviour for me, because I though that `webSocket` function will behave similar to `coroutineScope` standard function, which waits for all attached coroutines to finish before continue execution.

This bug was very hard to spot for me, so I want to understand the design of `webSocket` function more deeply. So, I have the following questions:

1. Why `webSocket` function don't wait for attached coroutines? Is it a bug or a intentional decision?
2. What is the conventions about functions that deal with `coroutineScope`-s? Should I always guard my coroutines with known standard library functions (like `coroutineScope`)? Or should library writers follow some guidelines - for example, always wait for all attached coroutines in scope to finish?

Comment: The `Route.webSocket()` [Documentation](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-features/ktor-websockets/io.ktor.websocket/web-socket.html) states that "Once `handler` function returns, the websocket termination sequence will be scheduled[...]". So it's definitely not a bug, but expected (and documented) behavior. I don't know for sure why they went with that design, but my guess is that they wanted to make it more obvious when a connection gets terminated: exactly when the handler function returns.

Comment: Shame on me - missed that part in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This behavior was implemented long ago without [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency) in mind. I'd say it's a **problem** that can be fixed on the Ktor side so I've created [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4110) to address it. A fix will make it easier to write Websocket handlers and will improve readability.
2. It depends on whether library maintainers consider supporting structured concurrency or not for a particular case.